# Stretchable UIImage and CGAffineTransform

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uiscrollview, uiimage

I've got a `UIScrollView` whose zoom behavior I want to confine to the horizontal axis. I've accomplished that through using a custom `UIView` as the `viewForZoomingInScrollView:` and overriding `setTransform:`. So far so good – the view only zooms horizontally.

One catch: The container view includes some stretchable `UIImage` instances in `UIImageView`s. Obviously, with the transform in effect, the images distort.

What's the best bet for either redrawing the view so that the images aren't distorted, or, zooming the view in such a way as to not require transforms in the first place?

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: I think the distortion depends on the order that the stretching and affine transformations are applied. I'm not familiar with the iphone API. Is it possible to reverse the order of the transformations?

Comment: I don't think so. The stretchability of a UIImage instance is set on init, then when you resize the frame of a UIImageView that's displaying it, the image renders according to the left and top margins you initially specified. Since as far as the UIImageView is concerned its frame hasn't changed when its superview's transform is applied, the image isn't redrawn.

Answer (score 0):

You sure way of achieving this is to make your UIImageView into a custom UIView, and have its `drawRect:` code do the right thing: draw both stretched and unstretched elements.